# How to use regex to extract links from HTML tag-attributes (src, data, href, or others)

Tags: regex

I have an HTML doc as string and would like to extract all it's links with one regex command/pattern (for better performance), instead of searching for every tag separately (which is the only way I know to solve it).

HTML example:

```
<a href="..."></a>
<img src="..." data-full-resolution="..." />
<object data="..."/>
```

Please consider also that the image tag has two attributes that should be extracted (`src` and `data-full-resolution`).

The programming language is intentionally left-out as I need a 'raw' solution, **without HTML librarires**.

Comment: Try `re.findall(r"(?:data-full-resolution|src|href|data)=\"(.*?)\"", html)`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks! ( PS - how did you know I'm using python :D )

Comment: You're welcome :) (The top tag of your profile is the `python`)

Comment: are you going to write also an answer so that I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:data-full-resolution|src|href|data)=\"(.*?)\"
```

##### Regex Explanation

- `(?:` Non-capturing group

  - `data-full-resolution|src|href|data` One of `data-full-resolution`, `src`, `href` or `data`
- `)` Close non-capturing group
- `=\"` Match `="` after an attribute name
- `(` Capturing group

  - `.*?` Non-greedy capturing till the next quote
- `)` Close group
- `\"` Match the close quote

See regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mvoLWS/1)

##### Python Example

```
import re

html = """<a href="<link-href>"></a>
<img src="<link-src>" data-full-resolution="<link-data-full-resolution>" />
<object data="<link-data>"/>"""

print(re.findall(r"(?:data-full-resolution|src|href|data)=\"(.*?)\"", html))  # ['<link-href>', '<link-src>', '<link-data-full-resolution>', '<link-data>']
```

Where `re.findall` returns the list of captured groups.